# What does "ahueca, muñeca" mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos

**Primero mi pregunta en español:**

¿Qué significa "ahueca, muñeca"?

**Details in English:**

In an effort to become more conversational in Spanish, I've been trying to learn a few more words and phrases that would be considered slang, colloquial, or informal including sayings from past decades. I've been able to find translations (or near translations) and/or good contextual clues for all but this one here — ahueca, muñeca.  I know that "ahuecar" means "to hollow out" and "muñeca" can mean "doll" or "wrist," but assumptions based off of just that don't leave me with a good feeling that I know how this phrase is (or has been used).  I've seen the phrase "ahuecar el ala" translated as "to get out,"* but I'm not sure if it means the same thing without the "el ala."

---

**Source: WordReference Thread: [**Ahuecar el ala**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ahuecar-el-ala.1108115/)*

---

---

Any ideas?

**Detalles en español:**

En un esfuerzo para ser más conversacional en español, he estado tratando de aprender algunas palabras y frases que serían consideradas jerga, coloquial, o informal, entre ellas, dichos de décadas pasadas.  He sido capaz de encontrar traducciones y/o buenas claves contextuales para todos excepto este de aquí — ahueca, muñeca.  Sé que “ahuecar” significa “to hollow out” y “muñeca” puede significar “doll” o “wrist,” pero suposiciones basadas en sólo eso no me da confianza que sé cómo esta frase se usa (o se ha utilizado en el pasado).  He visto la frase “ahuecar el ala” traducido como “to get out”,* pero no estoy segura que significa la misma cosa sin “el ala.”

---

**Fuente: Hilo de WordReference: [**Ahuecar el ala**](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ahuecar-el-ala.1108115/)*

---

¿Algunas ideas?

Comment: Maybe it was at one time a reference to China Dolls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, if you use the verb *[ahuecar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1JgKdSV)* in a conversation in imperative form, most surely it is going to be followed by *el ala*. In Spanish quite often we do not need to say the whole expression because with the first part of it the second part is implied, note that the Spanish definition for *ahuecar* already redirects you to *ahuecar el ala*, without the need to say *el ala*. And *[muñeca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Q6AmRPw)* is used to address to a woman in a Humphrey-Bogart-in-Casablanca style. I mean, quite outdated (as is *ahuecar el ala*) and with a bit of macho style, because the word makes you think in a young, beautiful woman, the type of woman a man would want to impress. I've never used that word in that way, in fact I have only heard it in movies. In real life it is more used to refer to very young girls and boys (*mira qué niña más guapa, parece una muñequita* could be fine if you speak about a two-year-old girl, and my granny could certainly say that my one-year-old baby is *un muñeco*).

So, *ahueca, muñeca* has the funny sound of the two words rhyming, but it also sounds like *sal de mi vista, mujer, que voy a tratar cosas de hombres*. I would not recommend you using it in conversation unless you are joking with your friends.

Comment: Excellent answer.  It answered my question and added details beyond the basic.  Bien hecho.  Gracias.